# python function defined but raises NameError

Tags: python, scope, namespaces

Environment:
Opensuse Linux 42.3, python 3.4.6, running under eclipse

For an automated test system I generate python scripts from test cases.
Executing the scripts runs into an error

```
NameError: name 'setVariable' is not defined
```

The generated scripts import a module named testfunc which defines the functions:

testfunc.py:

```
import sys

print("defining 'saveDeviceStatus'")
def saveDeviceStatus(devicePath,fq_fileName):
    print("ssaveDeviceStatus:")
    print("device '%s'" % devicePath)
    print("filePath '%s'" % fq_fileName)

print("defining 'setVariable'")
def setVariable(path,value):
    print("setVariable:")
    print("path '%s'" % path)
    print("value '%s'" % value)

print("defining 'compareDeviceStatus'")
def compareDeviceStatus(device,filename,options):
    print("compareDeviceStatus:")
    print("device '%s'" % device)
    print("filename '%s'" % filename)
    print(options)

print("defining 'checkResults'")
def checkResults(checkList):
    print("checkResults:")
    print(checkList)
```

A generated script looks like this:

t_0030_1206_001.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#
import time
import os,sys
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("testFunctions", "../")
sys.path.append("/home/heinrich/git/swisbox/swibTestPy/pyLib/")
import testfunc

os.chdir('/home/heinrich/git/swisbox/swib61850/test/tryAutomation/nanopi/pilot_dal-static-lib/180525T093506/')
sys.path.append('/home/heinrich/git/swisbox/swibTestPy/src/testlinkFiles/')


# draw actual status
saveDeviceStatus("SWIBCLS1","beforeSwitch_to_1")

checkResults([
    compareDeviceStatus("SWIBCLS1","beforeSwitch_to_1",["nodate"])
    ])
```

Executing a script outputs

```
$ ./t_0030_1206_001.py 
defining 'saveDeviceStatus'
defining 'setVariable'
defining 'compareDeviceStatus'
defining 'checkResults'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t_0030_1206_001.py", line 17, in <module>
    saveDeviceStatus("SWIBCLS1","beforeSwitch_to_1")
NameError: name 'saveDeviceStatus' is not defined
$
```

Although the print statements are executed, (to me) indicating the functions were defined, calling them results in an error. What am I missing here? What additional diagnostics could I run?

Comment: Reconsideing the python import system should be a good idea - thank you very much for pointing me to this. The names used may indeed seem unPythonic - many of them stem from API libs generated from C/C++ programs using SWIG.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

mod.py:

```
def my_fun():
    print ("Hello, world")
```

main.py:

```
import mod
my_func()
```

executing:

```
python3 main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    my_func()
NameError: name 'my_func' is not defined
```

you can fix by either importing the function

```
from mod import my_fun
```

or by using:

```
mod.my_fun()
```

So, in your case, use: `testfunc.saveDeviceStatus(..)` or use `from testfunc import saveDeviceStatus`

Answer (score 0):

For a start, that error is complaining about `saveDeviceStatus`, not `setVariable`.

It should not surprise you though; you don't import `saveDeviceStatus` anywhere. You *do* import `testfunc`; so you should refer to the functions via that name.

```
testfunc.saveDeviceStatus("SWIBCLS1","beforeSwitch_to_1")

testfunc.checkResults([
    testfunc.compareDeviceStatus("SWIBCLS1","beforeSwitch_to_1",["nodate"])
])
```

Also note this is all very unPythonic; you should use `lower_case_with_underscores` for function names, not `camelCase`.